# How to create *and populate* a table if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I developed my database by hand, and now have my app running on my development PC.

When it is deployed on a new machine, I want it to create the d/b structure if it is not already present.

So, I used `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` and copied the outputs into some MySQl commands `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` which is executed when my app starts, one command for each table.

However, although the data tables should be empty on a new PC - there is one configuration table (with a single row) which I want to populate to default values if not already present.

What's the simplest (most elegant?) way to do that? `SELECT *` from the table and check row count against zer0, inserting defaults if necessary?

Is there something simpler (or "better")? What is standard practise?

Thanks

Comment: You answered your own question. If num_rows==0, insert data!

Comment: +1 @BenKirchner Feel free to post that as an answer ...  It may be a dumb question, but I would like to know how others approach it, or if there is some fancy option to update or replace which I am not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any more elegant way to do it than you already suggested: if num_rows==0, insert data! Nothing there could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable AS SELECT * from originaltable;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config ...` as usual, and then in your application read your config table. If that table reads no data, `INSERT` row with default values and you're done.

Also you can have that config table have one row with unique key, and use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip insert default row if row was already there.